# List Index out of Range: Python, Tensorflow RNN

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow

There is an error saying list index out of range. I think it's because I'm predicting the next number. I'm following this article https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Creating-Text-Generator-Using-Recurrent-Neural-Network/ as a basis for predicting the next number in a list but I am struggling to align the ideas.

```
data = ['1','0','0','1','4','2','6','1','1','0','0','1','4','2']
chars = list(set(data))

VOCAB_SIZE= len(chars)
number_of_sequences= 1
SEQ_LENGTH=2
#Prepare training data

ix_to_char={ix:char for ix, char in enumerate(chars)}
char_to_ix={char:ix for ix, char in enumerate(chars)}

X= np.zeros((len(data)/SEQ_LENGTH, SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))
y= np.zeros((len(data)/SEQ_LENGTH, SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))

for i in range(len(data)/SEQ_LENGTH):
    X_sequence = data[i*SEQ_LENGTH:(i+1)*SEQ_LENGTH]
    X_sequence_ix=[char_to_ix[value] for value in X_sequence]
    input_sequence= np.zeros((SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))

    for j in range(0,SEQ_LENGTH):
        input_sequence[j][X_sequence_ix[j]]=1
    X[i]=input_sequence

    y_sequence = data[i*(SEQ_LENGTH+1):(i+1)*(SEQ_LENGTH+1)]
    y_sequence_ix = [char_to_ix[value] for value in y_sequence]
    target_sequence= np.zeros((SEQ_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE))

    for j in range(0,SEQ_LENGTH):
        target_sequence[j][y_sequence_ix[j]]=1 #LIST INDEX OUT OF RANGE

    y[i]=target_sequence
```

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Try looping with `for i in range(len(data) / SEQ_LENGTH) - 1:`

Comment: I put a while loop around my for loop and that worked also. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps not, I tried your method and still got the same outcome on indexing error...

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement loop within your for loop to prevent your code from indexing the list out of range.

use a condition like :

`for i in range(len(data)/SEQ_LENGTH):
    if ((i+1)*SEQ_LENGTH) < len(data): 
          X_sequence = data[i*SEQ_LENGTH:(i+1)*SEQ_LENGTH]`